# SQL to eliminate equal and exact opposite aggregated balances

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a sql to eliminate equal and exact opposite aggregated balances and below SQL does the job and eliminates individual txns with equal & opposite amts, but remaining the results gets aggregated and still has few balances which are equal and opposite post aggregation, how could i eliminate those in SQL ? any pointer would be helpful

```
SELECT SETID,   CONSOLIDATION_SET,  TREE_NAME,  TREE_NODE,  CONSOL_ENTITY,  SET_IDENTIFIER, LOG_ENTRY_TYPE, AS_OF_DATE, BUSINESS_UNIT,  LEDGER, ACCOUNT,    DEPTID, PRODUCT,    AFFILIATE,  CURRENCY_CD,    SUM(POSTED_TOTAL_AMT)
FROM PS_CONSOL_LOG A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_CONSOL_LOG B
WHERE A.SETID = B.SETID
AND A.CONSOLIDATION_SET = B.CONSOLIDATION_SET
AND A.SET_IDENTIFIER = B.SET_IDENTIFIER
AND A.CONSOL_ENTITY =B.CONSOL_ENTITY
AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.AFFILIATE 
AND A.AFFILIATE = B.BUSINESS_UNIT
AND A.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT = -B.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT)
GROUP BY SETID, CONSOLIDATION_SET,  TREE_NAME,  TREE_NODE,  CONSOL_ENTITY,  SET_IDENTIFIER, LOG_ENTRY_TYPE, AS_OF_DATE, BUSINESS_UNIT,  LEDGER, ACCOUNT,    DEPTID, PRODUCT,    AFFILIATE,  CURRENCY_CD
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is just too hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you can have 2 $150.00 positive amounts in one business unit and only one offsetting $-150.00 amount in the other.  You really need to number all of your positive and negative transactions of the same amount and use that as part of your join so you only pair off amounts once.

```
With Ordered_Amts as (
    Select SETID, CONSOLIDATION_SET, TREE_NAME,  TREE_NODE,
           CONSOL_ENTITY,  SET_IDENTIFIER, LOG_ENTRY_TYPE,
           AS_OF_DATE, BUSINESS_UNIT,  LEDGER, ACCOUNT, DEPTID,
           PRODUCT, AFFILIATE, CURRENCY_CD, POSTED_TOTAL_AMT,
           ROW_NUMBER() Over 
             (Partition by setid, CONSOLIDATION_SET, SET_IDENTIFIER, CONSOL_ENTITY, BUSINESS_UNIT, AFFILIATE, POSTED_TOTAL_AMT) as Nth_Entry
    From PS_CONSOL_LOG
)
Select SETID, CONSOLIDATION_SET, TREE_NAME, TREE_NODE,
      CONSOL_ENTITY, SET_IDENTIFIER, LOG_ENTRY_TYPE, AS_OF_DATE,
      BUSINESS_UNIT, LEDGER, ACCOUNT, DEPTID, PRODUCT, AFFILIATE,
      CURRENCY_CD, SUM(POSTED_TOTAL_AMT)
From Ordered_Amts A Left Outer Join Ordered_Amts B
     On A.SETID = B.SETID
     AND A.CONSOLIDATION_SET = B.CONSOLIDATION_SET
     AND A.SET_IDENTIFIER = B.SET_IDENTIFIER
     AND A.CONSOL_ENTITY =B.CONSOL_ENTITY
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.AFFILIATE 
     AND A.AFFILIATE = B.BUSINESS_UNIT
     And A.Nth_Entry = B.Nth_Entry
     AND A.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT = -B.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT
Where B.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT is null
GROUP BY SETID, CONSOLIDATION_SET, TREE_NAME, TREE_NODE,
    CONSOL_ENTITY, SET_IDENTIFIER, LOG_ENTRY_TYPE, AS_OF_DATE,
    BUSINESS_UNIT, LEDGER, ACCOUNT, DEPTID, PRODUCT, AFFILIATE,
    CURRENCY_CD
```

Comment: Hi chris-maurer, is it possible to sum the amounts and then order/rank them that way i will also be able to eliminate any transactions where two rows of 150 can be knocked off against one row of 300 for the given parameters ?

Comment: If I understand  what you are asking, among the 2^n+1 partial sums of posted amounts in one business unit are there any that match the 2^m+1 partial sums in another unit? If so, remove all the transactions that made up each of those partial sums, remove all the other partial sums containing those posted amounts and continue  checking.  I'm afraid you are way beyond SQL's capability with this.